# Click on Invisible/Overlapped Element

Tags: jscript, testcomplete

I have a pageParent with an overlapping pageChild. Attempts to call the Click() method on either page throw an OnOverlappingWindow event. Calling the Activate() method on either page before clicking won't change this. Suppressing the *overlapping window* error results in an *invisible or out of bounds* error.

```
function GeneralEvents_OnOverlappingWindow(Sender, Window, OverlappingWindow, LogParams)
{
   LogParams.Locked = true; //prevent error
}
```

I would like to get the coordinates of the intended click, and just click arbitrarily using those coordinates. How might I achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found out a reasonable method. I called obj.WindowToScreen(obj.Width/2, obj.height/2) to get the screen coordinates at the center of the window, then used LLPlayer.KeyDown and LLPlayer.KeyUp with those coordinates to simulate the click.